# ArgumentOutOfRangeException on Android Nougat when changing Grouped ItemSource

Tags: xamarin.forms

The first ItemSource has one section and the ItemSource that is switched to has two sections. It seems like Xamarin.Forms is looking for the section at index 1 in the first ItemSource (the one with only one section) and fails. [See bugzilla for more information and reproduction project.](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51704)
Only occurs on Android Nougat. I can post code if necessary but it's all in bugzilla already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this was related to having accessibility services turned on. This forced the ListView to try to access items before the internal items of the adapter were updated, resulting in the ArgumentOutOfRange exception.